# gnuplot, not including a line in data fit

Tags: gnuplot, data-fitting

I have a .dat file which I create in the following format:

```
q h error
```

The first line of data is not relevant for the fit. Does setting the xrange to not include the undesired point, mean that this value will not be used in the fit?

Answer (score 2):

There are two main lines you could proceed:

1. Put a `#` in front of your first line like:

   ```
   # q h error
   ```
2. Use [every](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_4.2/gnuplot.html#x1-12200034.1.3) to skip the first line of your data file like so:

   ```
   plot 'Data.dat' every 1::2
   ```

   The same thing also holds for `fit`. The only data modifier that is not allowed with `fit` is `smooth`.